# 1) Issue In Normalize Transformation for Informatica Power Center

Tags: pivot, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am Trying to Normalize Records of My SOurce table using Normalize Transformation in informatica, But Sequence are not re-generating for different rows.

Below Is SOurce Table :

```
Store_Name  Sales_Quarter1  Sales_Quarter2  Sales_Quarter3  Sales_Quarter4
DELHI       150             240             455             100
MUMBAI      100             500             350             340
```

Target Table :

```
Store_name
Sales
Quarter
```

I am Using Occurrence - 4, on Sales Column for getting GCID Sales.

For Quarter, I am Using GCID Sales column :

O/P :

```
STORE_NAME  SALES_COLUMN    QUARTER
Mumbai      100         1
Mumbai          500         2
Mumbai          350         3
Mumbai          340         4
Delhi           150         5
Delhi           240         6
Delhi           455         7
Delhi           100         8
```

Why Quarter Value is not restarting from 1 for Delhi and is continuing from 5 ?

Comment: This appears to be almost the same as the example given in Informatica documentation which is supposed to work the way you described. Could you share the screenshot of the normalizer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a GK column that keeps sequential numbers for all rows. Definitely, GCID is the right column that keeps numbers per multi-occurrences in a row. So, double check that there is GCID port and not GK that is linked to QUARTER port to target…
It’s good to provide a screenshot for the mapping and for the normalizer transformation (Normalizer tab) to be more informative about your question/issue…
But I suppose you have 'Store_Name' port at level 1 and all 'Sales_Quarter1', 'Sales_Quarter2', 'Sales_Quarter3' and 'Sales_Quarter4' ports **grouped** at level 2 on Normalizer tab (using >> button at top left area). And at group level (for these four ports) you set the Occurrence to 4.